# "Network Information" cordova plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am currently working on a rather large PhoneGap project using a handful of cordova plugins and I'm experiencing dificulties using the Network Information plgin to retrieve the connection type of the device.

It should be noted that I'm using the command line tool to build my PhoneGap project, not Adobe's "Build" service.

The versions of the phonegap and cordova cli tools are the following:

```
% phonegap -v
4.2.0-0.23.0
% cordova -v
4.2.0
```

Here is the list of plugins currently in use:

```
% phonegap plugins
com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot 0.1.0 "Screenshot"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.14 "SocialSharing"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
```

Here is the code responsible for using the plugin, it's located in a much larger object and is only called when I open to a certain page of the project:

```
checkDeviceConnexion:function(){
    require(['cordova', 'cordova_plugins'], function(cordova){
        checkConnexion();
    });
    function networkConnexion(){
        if (navigator.connection.type == 'none'){ //Connection.NONE
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function checkConnexion(){
        if (!networkConnexion()){
            app.showMsgError(tradu[lang]['msg-error-connexion']);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing my tests on android therefor I'm using adb as a mean to debug the application. When I run the code above, this is what I get:

```
I/chromium(12465): [INFO:CONSOLE(1145)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js (1145)
```

I scrapped and rebuilt the android project several times to make sure that all plugins were properly copied but it didn't help.

What's even more puzzling is that the output of the adb hints that somehow somewhere the network manager should be working properly as shown here:

```
D/CordovaNetworkManager(21764): Connection Type: wifi
D/CordovaNetworkManager(21764): Connection Extra Info: "atelier8"
```

But I'm unable to see the connection property in the navigator object.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for any tip or answer.

Comment: Check if navigator.connection is undefined on deviceready

Comment: I forgot to mention that the app uses requirejs too. Anyway, I added

    require(["cordova"], function(cordova) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',alert(navigator.connection.type),false);
   });

At the begging of the whole script and I sill get :

D/CordovaLog(20557): file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 2 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I'm having similar issues with my app.

Comment: Still nothing, sorry. Keep me posted if you find something too!

Comment: Check your DeviceReady must not be getting called. If it doesn't, none of the plugins you have would work.